# Composite types based on another type

Tags: typescript

I have a type that defines shared keys:

**INPUT**

```
export type LocalesT =
  'some' |
  'keys'
```

Now I need two interfaces (or types), where in the first everything is optional and in the second everything is required. All keys contain a `string`:

**TARGET**

```
export interface LocalesCustomI {
  some?: string
  keys?: string
}

export interface LocalesInternalI {
  some: string
  keys: string
}
```

**CURRENT (WRONG) SOLUTION**

```
export type LocalesCustomT = Record<LocalesT, string>
export type LocalesInternalT = Record<LocalesT, string>
```

The current solution does not cause any error. In the latter case, this may be a problem. I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, but wouldn't `Partial` and `Required` solve this for you?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz You understood me well. Thank you for the guidance. Does that mean it's okay for my case like this?
`export type LocalesCustomT = Record<Partial<TLocale>, string>
export type LocalesInternalT = Record<Required<TLocale>, string>`

Comment: Yeah that would be fine

Comment: Thank you very much @MuratKaragöz, post an answer if you want me to mark it as correct.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Unfortunately I found that the `Partial` does not work as it should. if I delete one of the keys, it throws me an error `property x is missing on type LocalesCustomT`.

Comment: Use it like this `Partial<Record<LocalesT, string>>`

Comment: @MuratKaragöz That makes sense... Now it works like a charm. Thank you!